# How to add types for jest test with describe.each?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

```
const has = (object: Record<string, unknown>, key: string) => {
    return object != null && hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)
};
```

**has.test.ts**

```
describe('has', () => {
    const obj = {
        name: 'name',
        1: 1,
        false: false,
        undefined: undefined
    };
    describe.each([
        ['name', true],
        [1, true],
        [false, true],
        [undefined, true],
        ['no-such-key', false]
    ])('when key = %s', (key, expected) => {
        it(`should return ${expected}`, () => {
            expect(has(obj, key)).toBe(expected);
        });
    });
});
```

[image]

Does anyone have experience adding types for jest tests? I am using `describe.each` to loop over datasets. Though I am able to run the tests successfully, I want to fix that typing issue. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 23):

It seems that you don't have latest version of types for jest, try to update package `@types/jest` to latest version (it contains type definition for [Each](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jest/index.d.ts#L294) interface).

If that's not possible for some reasons you can always "extend" the types yourself using typescript feature called [declaration-merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html):

```
// jest.d.ts file

declare namespace jest {

  interface Each {
    // Exclusively arrays.
    <T extends any[]>(cases: ReadonlyArray<T>): (name: string, fn: (...args: T) => any, timeout?: number) => void;
    // Not arrays.
    <T>(cases: ReadonlyArray<T>): (name: string, fn: (...args: T[]) => any, timeout?: number) => void;
    (cases: ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyArray<any>>): (
        name: string,
        fn: (...args: any[]) => any,
        timeout?: number
    ) => void;
    (strings: TemplateStringsArray, ...placeholders: any[]): (
        name: string,
        fn: (arg: any) => any,
        timeout?: number
    ) => void;
  }

  interface Describe {
    each: Each
  }
}
```

You might need also to specify [typeRoots](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) configuration option so that typescript can pick up your custom types

**Upd:**
Sorry, I just noticed that your issue is not in absence of `Each` interface but in *incorrect type*.
It seems that in your case typescript cannot infer the type correctly so you might want to specify generic type explicitly, e.g.:

```
type TestTuple = [string | number | boolean, boolean];

describe.each<TestTuple>([
  ['name', true],
  [1, true],
  [false, true],
  [undefined, true],
  ['no-such-key', false]
])('when key = %s', (a, b) => {
    // do your stuff
});
```

Comment: "@types/jest": "^24.0.15"
this is what I am using. Its not that old version. I checked node_modules. jest/index.d.ts contain typing for Each

Comment: @Ich so there is no need to extend the type, it is already there. I've updated my comment with more information, this should work for you.